# How do I start Chrome with specific window size, position, and profile?

Tags: windows, command-line, google-chrome, batch, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to open Chrome to a specific user while also having a specific window size and position using CMD on Windows.  It seems that I can either open to a specific profile or mess with the window sizing and positioning,
but not both at the same time.

Window size/position seems to only work if I use `--user-data-dir`.  Without that, it doesn't change at all.

But once I add `--user-data-dir` to the command, I can't specify what profile I want to use (typically done using `--profile-directory`).

This is not working:

`start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window %option% --window-size="400,300" --window-position="0,0" --user-data-dir="C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" --profile-directory="Profile 4"`

Comment: Add the following info to your question: What version windows? 32 or 64-bit?  What version chrome? [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962811/8826818)